# While holding the key (c# unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity I want my character to crouch while ctrl button is being clicked, for this I wrote this code, but it does not work unfortunately.

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = crouchedSprite;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you call this code?

Comment: In Update function.

Comment: What do you mean its doesn't work?

Comment: It stays crouched after the ctrl button is clicked, I want it to crouch while the key is being clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the sprite after key is released.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        print("LeftControl pressed.");
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = crouchedSprite;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        print("LeftControl released.");
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = normalSprite;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `GetComponent` every update. It causes an unnessessary overhead. Call it once in `Awake` and store in a field.

Change your code to this, it should work:

```
spriteRenderer.sprite =
Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) ? crouchedSprite : normalSprite;
```